# How to alter an event in mysql which is already created

Tags: mysql, events

Can anyone give me syntax to alter an event which has been already created

Here i have created an event with the following syntax

```
create event _insert on schedule at '2012-10-08 17:09' + interval 10 second do insert into event_test values(now());
```

and now i want to change the interval time from 10 seconds to 1minute

Here is the table creation syntax for event_test table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testing`.`event_test`;CREATE TABLE  `testing`.`event_test` (`current_date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`current_date_time`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a simple alter command ?

```
ALTER event _insert 
   ON SCHEDULE AT '2012-10-08 17:09' + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE -- or new date 
   DO INSERT INTO event_test VALUES(now());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
'      ALTER EVENT event _insert
       ON SCHEDULE schedule 
       DO
       INSERT INTO event_test VALUES(now());
```